# Cannot calculate the time difference using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I need to calculate the datetime difference in `minutes` using PHP. I am explaining my code below .

```
$date='10-03-2018 03:44 PM';
$endTime = strtotime($date);
$currentDate=date("d-m-Y h:i A");//10-03-2018 03:53 PM
$currentTime = strtotime($currentDate);
echo (round(abs($currentTime - $endTime) / 60,2));//25344617
```

Here I need to calculate the difference in `minutes` but the differnce value is more where the expected time difference should be `9` but as per my code I am getting the wrong value.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE, in particular the V part is not provided, since the results change with the time.

Comment: better make use of the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Answer (score 1):

Let the PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class with [diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method do the work with time calculations.

```
$now = '10-03-2018 03:53 PM'; // or use simply 'now' for current time
$endTime = '10-03-2018 03:44 PM';
$datetime1 = new DateTime($now);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($endTime);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%i  minutes'); // 9  minutes
```

See it live: https://eval.in/969615